# Rank of projection and error matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $C_{n \times p}$, whose columns are linearly independent and all  elements in the first column are $1$, let $D = I_n - C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$.
>
> 1. Prove $D.{\bf 1}=0$, where ${\bf 1}=(1,1,1,1..,1)^T$?
> 2. Find the rank of $D$?

Clearly $C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$ is the projection matrix, so $I_n - C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$ is the error vector which is perpendicular to the column space of $C$. So $D.1=0$. My doubts are the following

1. But how do I find the rank of $D$?
2. Also what will be the rank of $C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $D$ is a projection we know that 
$$\eqalign{\hbox{rk}(D_n)&=\hbox{Tr}(D_n)=n-\hbox{Tr}(C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T)\cr
&
=n-\hbox{Tr}((C^TC)^{-1}C^TC)
=n-\hbox{Tr}(I_p)=n-p.}$$

Comment: I can't understand why $Tr(C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T) = Tr(I_p)$.

Comment: Because $\hbox{Tr}(AB)=\hbox{Tr}(BA)$, so with $A=C$, $B=(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$ we have $BA=(C^TC)^{-1}(C^TC)=I_p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.